# How can I make my webview load a url shared from another app?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, webview, shared

I'm new to developing, for my first app I'm trying to make a web browser. My problem is I cant get my webview to load a url from a shared Intent. All I get is a blank page. I've spent days searching the web, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

my code to get the intent (in oncreate and onresume)

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
        String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
        try {
            if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
                String receivedText = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if (receivedText != null) {
                if (receivedType.equals("text/plain")) {
                    webView.loadUrl(receivedText);
                }
            }
```

my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: Did you log the receivedText to make sure it's a valid URL?

Comment: @chRyNaN good thought! heres my log.

Comment: I/CLOCKS: CLOCKS Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/television-changes-channels-skinny-1.3465542?cmp=rss I/CLOCKS: CLOCKS android.intent.action.VIEW
I/CLOCKS: CLOCKS null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="org.sakaiproject.sakai.WebViewActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/webview_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now on the `Activity` you must get the url with `getDataString()`

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        // get the url
        url = getIntent().getDataString();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webview_progressbar);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        // update progressbar
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

and on the manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: In your code, url = getIntent().getDataString(); what is the "url" ?

Comment: hehe I forgot to declare it...it's a String

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!